# How do I rename multiple files by removing a particular name, whitespace and add a unique string?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, rename

I have *n* number of files I want to rename by removing a particular name, whitespace, and I want to add a unique string with the new name:

E.g.

```
"MPKL 100055.jpg" 
"MPKL 200452.jpg" 
"MPKL 500002_thumb.jpg"
```

I want to rename the above files to:

```
"00100055.jpg"
"00200452.jpg"
"00500002_thumb.jpg"
```

Two zeros have to come in front of the existing number.

Comment: You want to replace "MKPL " with "00", right? Is that all you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below example I used a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to set delimiters and tokens parsing file name parts and use those to set variables for later use with the [REN](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command. I've also utilized the [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to handle the expanding of the variables set in the loop accordingly to be properly used (not parsed at runtime) with the rename command per iteration within the loop.

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tester

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=. " %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*.jpg"') DO (
    SET "part1=%%~F" 
    SET "part2=%%~G" 
    SET "part3=%%~H"
    REN "%SourceDir%\!part1! !part2!.!part3!" "00!part2!.!part3!"
)
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [**REN**](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)

Comment: Yes this code gave me correct soluton. Thank You PIMP_JUICE_IT

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=MPKL" 

Set "Replace=00"

For %%# in ("FOLDER_PATH/*.jpg") Do (

    Set "File=%%~nx#"

    Ren "%%#" "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"


)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: I run the above command in cmd "f was unexpected at this time" like this error came.

Comment: Was it working ?

Comment: I want to run in windows.

Comment: Could you give me solution for Windows. @ Avani

Comment: I have edited answer.

Comment: Avani your edited code gave result as 00 400006.jpg here space has to remove after two zeros.  New Name has to be like this 00400006.jpg.

Comment: I welcome any expert could give solution in command line for my query.

Comment: I have added code for removing space in answer .this can be applied for bulk of file.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 1):

I rename files a lot, and I find it very convenient to use [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php). It is free. You can rename files and folders in folders and/or subfolders in many ways, including changing the extensions.